# Yii 2.0 - Error Message in Minimum Number Validation In Yii2.0

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-validation

I am having trouble locating the error message of the Minimum Number Validation.. i tried overwriting it with this code

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
                [['login_name'], 'string', 'min' => 5, 'message' => 'Please input more than 5 characters.'],
               ];
    }
```

but it did not change the default error message which is:

> The login name must be at least five characters.

i wanna know where the default error message is..

and is there a way to overwrite this error message..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Chinmay Answer Is Correct*. It's Working. But, What Problem You Are Facing To Use It.

Comment: i was looking for a way to overwrite the default error message generated by yii.. i tried looking for it but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['login_name'], 'string', 'min' => 5, 'tooShort' => 'Please input more than 5 characters.'],
    ];
}
```

For more details refer to this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-stringvalidator.html#$tooShort-detail).

Comment: Thanks @Chinmay for your quick response. i was able to see that code but i don't know how to use it. i am new to yii2.. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It Worked. But, why OP has a problem in using it. +1 For You Brother.

Comment: Working, awesome :)